# Kernel config options explained

Tags: boot, kernel, options

Can anyone explain what the following options from my centos 5.9 box do

```
CONFIG_HAS_IOPORT=y
CONFIG_HAS_DMA=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IRQ_PROBE=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_PENDING_IRQ=y
CONFIG_X86_SMP=y
CONFIG_X86_HT=y
CONFIG_X86_BIOS_REBOOT=y
CONFIG_X86_TRAMPOLINE=y
CONFIG_KTIME_SCALAR=y
```

Comment: The kernel source is structured in a modular fashion with support for various features included based on compile time options like these. So what they *did* was cause support for those features to be included in the kernel when it was compiled.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your explanation. I know that these are kernel features but what I ment was what actually do these options.(?) What each option enables or disables in the kernel. I couldn't find a list explaining what they do so I asked here.